# Do primitive type names need to be uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

```js
/**
 * @param {String} foo
 * @param {Number} bar
 */
```

or

```js
/**
 * @param {string} foo
 * @param {number} bar
 */
```

JSDoc [`@type`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html) documentation is not being explicit about it.

I always uppercase `String` and `Number` because it is my understanding that I need to use the constructor name. In JavaScript, [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) exist as constructors.

I have noticed inconsistency: I am defining other primitive types (e.g. `null`, `undefined`) as lowercase.

Do primitive type names need to be uppercase or lowercase?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[It doesn't matter](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1046):

> JSDoc doesn't care. It's up to the user's preference. I tend to use lowercase for primitive types (and function, for some reason) and uppercase for Array and Object.

I tend to use lowercase because the `typeof` operator returns lowercase.

Comment: I have created an ESLint plugin that enforces consistent type case (among other things), https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc

Comment: Author of [the linked issue](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1046) here. If you look at how many other projects have been linking to that issue, it suggests that developers *are* looking for guidance. Saying "JSDoc doesn't care" ignores this quest for guidance.